# Display form data in new window

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to retrieve all form entries or some parts and publish it on another web page?

For example, I make a form that asks a particular question and upon submission, they will be redirected to a page where all past answers are displayed.

Is this possible in Cognito Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I work with the Cognito Forms team.
I am not aware of a feature to anonymously display form entries on a webpage from within Cognito Forms.
With our paid plan levels you can have the option to grant rights to multiple authenticated members to view entries, however I don't think this is what you were asking for.

If your intent was to display entries on a separate website then there may be several ways to export or send form entries to a website to be displayed.
In each of these cases however there would have to be some programming done on the remote website to display the entries.

- Export Form entries to CSV: Form Entries can be exported to a CSV format file and the data reused wherever it is needed
- Cognito Webhooks: [Post JSON data to a website](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/66/data-integration/webhooks) option. Setup Cognito forms to post form submission results to a remote website. Again some programming would need to be done to catch the data, save the data and display the data.
- Cognito Zapier Services integration: Cognito has a plugin to Zapier, it's still in beta but it works fine. Zapier is a cloud integration service that supports quick integration between different cloud apps with no coding so use of Zapier might be a good fit depending on what you were trying to do.

Here are a couple of blog articles where we discussing the Zapier integration and what sort of things you can do.

http://blog.cognitoapps.com/connect-your-cognito-forms-to-almost-anything-with-zapier
http://blog.cognitoapps.com/how-to-using-zapier-to-send-cognito-form-entries-to-trello